# tableViewの全セルを選択する方法

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

複数のセルを選択できるtableviewにおいて、ボタンを押した際に全セルが選択（チェックマークを入れる）されるようにしたいのですが方法がわかりません。ちなみに選択されたセルにチェックマークを入れる方法は下記で記述しています。

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let SelectCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    SelectCell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
}
```

例えばbarbuttonitemで全セル選択のようなボタンを配置したいと考えています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView`は、**MVCデザインパターン**に基づいて設計されています。MVCとは、「Model（データ）、View（表示）、Controller（仲介）」の略です。考え方は短時間で理解できるものではありませんが、`UITableView`に即したところだけ説明すると、データと表示を分けて考えようということです。
問題です。行が100あるテーブルがあるとします。画面上表示されているのは10行です。ではこのテーブルはいくつのセルを持っているでしょうか？実験してみるとわかりますが、セルは100個ではありません。表示最大行10プラスアルファの数しかありません。テーブルをスクロールして、非表示になったセルは、姿を変えて、すぐに新しく表示になるセルとなります。テーブルは、場合によっては数万行におよぶ巨大なデータを扱うこともあります。そういうケースでもメモリ消費を抑えるために、こういう仕組みをとっています。それを支えているのが、データと表示を切り離すMVCの考え方です。
前置きが長くなりましたが、セルにチェックマークを入れる外すというプログラムを考える前に、質問者さんのテーブルのプログラムを、最初から書き換えないといけないのではないか、ということがお分かりいただけますか？

サンプルプログラムを載せます。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    // テーブルに表示するデータを、配列で用意する。
    var dataArray: [[String: String]] = [[String: String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // データに、チェックマークをつけるかつけないかの項目を入れる。
        dataArray = [["name": "Apple", "check": "No"],
        ["name": "Banana", "check": "No"],
        ["name": "Candy", "check": "Yes"],
        ["name": "Donut", "check": "No"]]
    }

    // UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]["name"]
        // チェックマークをつけるかつけないかを、ここで指示。
        cell.accessoryType = dataArray[indexPath.row]["check"] == "Yes" ? UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark : .None

        return cell
    }

    // セルをタップして選択する時の処理。チェックマーク表示をトグルで切り替える。
    // 「didSelectRow〜」じゃなくて「willSelectRow〜」なのに注意。
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        // データを変更。
        let check = (dataArray[indexPath.row]["check"] == "Yes") ? "No" : "Yes"
    dataArray[indexPath.row]["check"] = check
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = (check == "Yes") ? .Checkmark : .None
        // セルの表示を変更。（注）
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = (check == "Yes") ? .Checkmark : .None

        return indexPath
    }

    // ボタンを押したら、全チェックにする。
    @IBAction func checkAll(sender: AnyObject) {
        // データを変更。
        for i in 0..<dataArray.count {
        dataArray[i]["check"] = "Yes"
    }
        // テーブルの再描画。
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

注：データを書き換えて、同時にセルのチェックマークの表示も切り替えるというのは、二度手間のように見えます。確かにそうで、ここは`tableView.reloadData()`でもいいのですが、表示のレスポンスが良くなるので、こうしています。

ポイントは、テーブルに表示するデータの構造を変更して、チェックマークの表示も情報として持つようにすること。テーブルにユーザ（人間）が変更を加えたら、それをデータに反映させるプログラムにするということです。